# General Gaussian integrals over the positive real axis.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, gaussian-integral

Everyone has a special memory from their multivariable calc class deriving the famous Gaussian integral:

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \,dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$

A more general case is easy to find online and (not too hard to do yourself):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2+bx+c} \,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}+c}$$

While I was trying to solve a certain Laplace Transform, I went looking for the answer to a similar generalization over the postive real axis:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2+bx+c} \, dx $$

Any help approaching this last question would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: It would be half the value of the original minus a constant multiple of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)$, the error function.

Comment: yes, it has to do with the normal distribution and due to its parity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also express the integral in terms of the [Lower incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
$$\int _0^{\infty }e^{-ax^2+bx+c}\:dx=e^c\underbrace{\int _0^{\infty }e^{-a\left(\left(x-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}\:dx}_{u=x-\frac{b}{2a}}$$
$$=e^c\int _{-\frac{b}{2a}}^{\infty }e^{-a\left(u^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}\:du$$
$$=e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int _{-\frac{b}{2a}}^{\infty }e^{-au^2}\:du=e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int _0^{\infty }e^{-au^2}\:du\:-e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}\underbrace{\int _0^{-\frac{b}{2a}}e^{-au^2}\:du}_{u=-u}$$
$$=e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int _0^{\infty }e^{-au^2}\:du\:+e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}\underbrace{\int _0^{\frac{b}{2a}}e^{-au^2}\:du}_{t=au^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{a}}\:e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}+\frac{e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{2\sqrt{a}}\int _0^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}e^{-t}\:t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\:dt=\frac{e^{c+\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{2\sqrt{a}}\left(\sqrt{\pi }+\gamma \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\right)$$
If you want to express it in terms of the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) you can use the following identity
$$\gamma \left(\frac{1}{2},x\right)=\sqrt{\pi }\:\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$

Comment: This looks great! Thank you very much.